# Kawasaki Vulcan 650 2015

Tags: warning-light

can anyone help please.   i have put a Delkevic exhaust on my vulcan s 650, and now the engine management light comes on!!!!!! Does anyone how can I turn it off please? I have checked all the wiring and connections.

Answer (score 1):

**NB:** This isn't *really* an answer yet (as that depends on what the code is) but this is too long for a comment!

I suspect the light is showing because the new exhaust's difference in flow/back pressure is causing the O2 sensor to get anomalous readings. But first things first you need to find out what the actual error code is:

***Reading error codes:***

1. Turn on ignition.
2. Push the upper meter button to display the odometer.
3. Push the upper meter button and left meter button for more than 2 seconds.
4. Error code should be displayed instead of the mileage (if there's more than one code logged it will cycle through them every couple of seconds)
5. When you're done just turn the ignition off

***What the codes mean:***

11 Main throttle sensor malfunction, wiring open or short.

12 Intake air pressure sensor malfunction, wiring open or short.

13 Intake air temperature sensor malfunction, wiring open or short.

14 Water temperature sensor malfunction, wiring open or short.

21 Crankshaft sensor malfunction, wiring open or short

24 Rear wheel rotation sensor malfunction, wiring open or short.

25 Gear position sensor malfunction, wiring open or short.

31 Vehicle-down sensor malfunction, wiring open or short.

32 Sub throttle sensor malfunction, wiring open or short.

33 Oxygen sensor malfunction or Inactivate, wiring open or short.

39 ECU communication error

41 Fuel injector #1 malfunction, wiring open or short.

42 Fuel injector #2 malfunction, wiring open or short.

51 Stick coil #1 malfunction, wiring open or short.

52 Stick coil #2 malfunction, wiring open or short.

56 Radiator fan relay malfunction, wiring open or short.

62 Subthrottle valve actuator malfunction, wiring open or short.

64 Air switching valve malfunction, wiring open or short.

67 Oxygen sensor heater malfunction, wiring open or short.

94 Fuel supply system malfunction

3A Purge valve malfunction, wiring open or short (Equipped Models).

I suspect you'll see code 33 if I'm right. At that point if the bike is actually *running* okay you can probably just leave it - clearing the code will just lead to it coming back sooner or later anyway.

Comment: I only have a left and right meter button.  I tried holding them down ,but that did not give me any codes, just tried to change the clock and other settings.

Comment: I am going to give it a blast to check that all is running ok.

Comment: I *think* if it's just for the two buttons you press the left one to cycle the display until it shows the odometer then press and hold the left for ~2secs but I'm not 100% sure on that!

Answer (score 0):

Of course, one possibility is to get a re-map including the new exhaust which should put the fault light out, but that also means getting the engine with new exhaust tested to provide the new characteristic map. Which will be expensive...

Answer (score -1):

You could try disconnecting the battery for a few minutes and maybe it will re-learn the new exhaust.

Comment: I have disconnected the senser and 'plugged ' the exhaust, and the light is still on......

Comment: The system is still detecting a fault as the sensor is now disconnected ...